# need logo in center of page section excluding left sidebar in squarespace

Tags: html, css, header, squarespace

website :https://wells-demo.squarespace.com/
Need logo in center of page section excluding left sidebar(header) in squarespace WELLS template on all format mobile,desktop etc.I am trying to figure out but no result.following is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#headerWrapper #header ').after('<div id="logo1"  data-content-field="site-title"><h1 class="logo image" data-shrink-original-size="23" style="letter-spacing: 0.0869565em;"><a href="/"><img src="//static1.squarespace.com/static/5adfd10929711421a9b29d21/t/5adfdbac562fa79909bad158/1524908392416/?format=750w" alt="L ETO BRIDAL" width="130"  height=50"></a></h1></div>');
});
```

```css
#logo{display:none;}
  #headerWrapper{top:4px!important}
  #logo1 h1  a img {
       height:70px!important;
    
      
  }
 #logo1 {
    left: 300%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center !important;
    top: 10px !important;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current CSS, this should do it:

```css
#logo {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  #logo {
    position: fixed;
    width: calc(100% - 340px);
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 240px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ffffff85;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  }
}
```

Note: in current form, your question is not really useful to future visitors.

Comment: Andrei I have added new logo so that left navigation can move up on top..and your code doesn't work for mobile https://wells-demo.squarespace.com/

Comment: @Mr7: I've added extra rules for handling cases below `800px`. And I don't know what you mean by *"I've added new logo so that left navigation can move up on top"*.

Comment: I am talking about my jquery code in question.forget this..and your code worked  for mobile ...and desktop there is problem in resoltuion 800*1200 and 1920 *900

Comment: My bad. should be `min-width:801px`, not `800px`. Can't reproduce your problem on `1920 * 900`. Consider adding a [mcve] here where I can experience it.

Comment: if you go here https://wells-demo.squarespace.com    i need logo all time in center of this block on website <section id="page" >  on 1920* 900..logo is not in center

Comment: When I gave the answer initially it was centered, but now it's not anymore. You must have made some change. I recentered it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170000/discussion-between-mr7-itsurdeveloper-and-andrei-gheorghiu).

Answer (score 0):

You can read the structure i made below using w3.css from w3schools. I have given a border colour to every div so you can see the boundary of that div and it will make it easy to learn for you.

```css
.outer
{
border:1px solid red;
min-height:100px;
width:100%;
}

.inner-left
{
border:1px solid green;
}

.inner-right
{
border:1px solid blue;
}

.centetr
{
text-align:center;
}

.photo
{
width:95%;
margin:0px auto;
height:40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> 

<div class="w3-container outer">

<!--left side-->
<div class="w3-quarter inner-left">
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="w3-rest inner-right">
<div class="w3-container w3-margin-bottom centetr">
NAME
</div>
<div class="w3-container">

<div class="w3-half">
<img src="" class="photo">
</div>

<div class="w3-half">
<img src="" class="photo">
</div>

<div class="w3-half">
<img src="" class="photo">
</div>

<div class="w3-half">
<img src="" class="photo">
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```